# Replace spaces in between single characters in Redshift (POSIX regex...ie no lookarounds)

Tags: regex, replace, posix, amazon-redshift

I am trying to delete whitespace in between single characters at the end of a string.

For example I would need this:

SOME COMPANY L L C

to become this:

SOME COMPANY LLC

The catch is that this is in Redshift, which only supports POSIX regular expressions, so I cannot use a lookahead (?=) which would make life too easy.

The closest thing I have so far is:

```
(\s.{1,3}$)
```

See here: https://regexr.com/3h81p

However this selects the letters too. I can't just replace the letters with LC because there are many more filings such as L P, L C, N A, so it would be very nice to just replace the whitespace between them.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you're going to provide a regexr link, why wouldn't you also provide example testcases?

Comment: Really POSIX BREs/EREs, or do you have `\<`, `\>`, `\s`, `\S` etc.?

Comment: Does it support `\b` (word boundary) and back-references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for:

```
(\s\w)\s(\w)\s?(\w?)$
```

Replace with:

```
$1$2$3
```

This should work for removing spaces between two singled-out characters or three singled-out characters at the end of a line.

Comment: Nice, this does work. Had to add extra escape though so: (\\s\\w)\\s(\\w)\\s?(\\w?)$